# retrieving PDF data from Firebase Storage issues in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

Trying to pull data from firebase but can't get it to work, it receives chunks and won't return full data blob.

```
@MainActor
func getEmailData() -> EmailData
{
    var dataAttachment:EmailData.AttachmentData?
    Task
    {
        let firebaseRepository = Storage.storage().reference().child(referral.cvStorageReference)
        firebaseRepository.getData(maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024)
        {
            data, error in
            
            
            dataAttachment = EmailData.AttachmentData(data: data!, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "file.pdf")
     
        }
    }
    return EmailData(attachments: [dataAttachment!])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should yes method `write(toFile:)`, because your method restricts file size to be only 5 Mb. Look at official [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files).

Comment: File size is not a concern 5mb is far more than enough for the use case.

Comment: Just try another method :)